# Bugzilla : Make user restrict to view bugs

Tags: bugzilla

I have a user which belongs to Group B.
I want him to restrict to view bugs for product for which group B is unchecked and NA/NA in edit group permissions.
Product is for Group A only. 
Still he can access bugs and also edit. I don't want that.

What more I have to do. Any more configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a two different group as per products.
Say For -

```
ProductA - Group A
ProductB - Group B
```

Then in

```
administrator---->Products----->Edit Group Controls
```

click on link. It will show you some setting for groups that newly created - Group A and Group B.

For product A then use group A setting -

```
mandatory/mandatory , editbugs
```

same for product B.

This will restrict A from accessing Product B and vice versa.

This works for me, I hope it may come to use to others too :)